# What is the new Jetbrains web-based code-browsing tool (based on IntelliJ)?

Tags: intellij-idea, upsource

Recently, I was watching a presentation in which JetBrains demonstrated a new, web-based code-browsing tool.

It's based on the IntelliJ code base, which supports code navigation operations such as show implementations, find usages, and so forth.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to find the presentation again. Does anyone know the name of this tool?

Since the tool is in pre-release, it wasn't possible to google any information about it. So thanks for any info!

Comment: they do not offer version control afaik, just check their website

Comment: please reread my question - it's nothing to do with version control, it's about web-based code browsing.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called JetBrains Upsource and you can see it in action at https://upsource.jetbrains.com/

Comment: But my firefox 20.0.1 is apparently out of date (and I have cookies enabled). Where can i read about supported browser versions?

Answer (score 3):

Upsource (that's the name of the tool) developer here. We just published a new preview build, by the way - check it out.

Regarding your browser compatibility question - I'm assuming you're getting an outdated browser warning, is it true? It shouldn't be the case with Firefox 20, though we generally support the last two released versions of every major browser (which, in case of Firefox, means 22 and 23). Upsource makes heavy use of latest web technologies to do what it does, therefore - no old browsers.